# How to make Recaptcha always show images

Tags: recaptcha

I want it to show up whenever the user enters the page
Even if google knows i'm human, i still want it to show up
Sorry for the stupid question. But do you have any solution?

[image]

Comment: increase the security index in your recaptcha configuration. (google dev console)

Comment: @N69S Can you help me in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your admin pannel for the recaptcha `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/site/{site number}` and click on the parameter wheel in the top right.

Scroll down and you will find `"Security preference"` scroll. just set it at max where it is labeled `"Most secure settings"`

Comment: I tried, but it not working, it not show in my Chrome

Comment: @ThinhNguyen You can't do anything more than that. but with that modification you mostly will land on the images as someone who did not validate a recaptcha recently. Either way, there is no risk that you get spammed.